# How to convert a byte array to a double (float value) in Dart

Tags: dart, floating-point, byte

Based on [this question](https://medium.com/@uploder1234/i-am-trying-to-extract-weights-and-biases-from-tflite-model-in-flutter-844672681926), I have a list of bytes in Dart:

```dart
final data = [123, 34, 106, 115, 111, 110, 114, 112, 99, 34, 58, 34, 50, 46, 48, 34, 44, 34, 109, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 34, 58, 34, 115];
```

It represents a Float32 value from [TensorFlow Lite](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite). How do convert that to a readable `double` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data contains 28 bytes, and since it represents 32-bit float values (each of which are 4 bytes), that's equivalent to seven 32-bit values.

```dart
final data = [
  123, 34,  106, 115,   // 1
  111, 110, 114, 112,   // 2
  99,  34,  58,  34,    // 3
  50,  46,  48,  34,    // 4
  44,  34,  109, 101,   // 5
  116, 104, 111, 100,   // 6
  34,  58,  34,  115,   // 7
];
```

The [`ByteData`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html) class from the [`dart:typed_data`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html) library gives you different views on byte data. What you want is the Float32 view, which will give you a `double` in Dart.

```dart
final bytes = Uint8List.fromList(data);
final byteData = ByteData.sublistView(bytes);
double value = byteData.getFloat32(0);
print(value); // 8.433111377393183e+35
```

The `0` in `getFloat32(0)` means that you want to get the 32-bit float value starting at index `0` in the byte array. That only gives you the first value of the seven, though, so if you want the rest you need to loop though the entire byte list:

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
  print(byteData.getFloat32(i));
}
```

On every loop you increase the index by 4 to get the beginning of the next 32-bit float value. Run that loop and you'll see the results for all seven values:

```
8.433111377393183e+35
7.3795778785962275e+28
2.9925614505443553e+21
1.0139077133430874e-8
2.308231080230816e-12
7.366162972792583e+31
2.522593777484324e-18
```

#### See also

- [Working with bytes in Dart](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-bytes-in-dart-6ece83455721)